# Configure Daily Volume Cap Warning Level via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template

Under the "Usage and estimated costs" blade for an Azure Application Insights instance, the "Daily cap" window allows for a warning to be sent when a certain percentage of the daily volume cap has been reached.

By default, this warning level is 90% - but it can be set to any percentage. Is there a way to set this percentage via an ARM template, instead of manually in the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example ARM template for setting app insights quota including the warning threshold is below.  This will set a limit of 5GiB with warning of 90% and resets at 23:00 each day.:

```json
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('appInsightsName'),'/Basic')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/CurrentBillingFeatures",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "CurrentBillingFeatures": "Basic",
        "DataVolumeCap": {
          "Cap": 5,
          "WarningThreshold": 90,
          "ResetTime": 23
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!